# Data not stored in Access db with C# ad.InsertCommand

Tags: c#, database-connection, ms-access-2010, sql-insert, oledbcommand

I have the following code in C#, for a interface with a DB. I introduce values in TextBoxes on the interface. No error, but when executed, data is not stored in the DB created with Microsoft Access 2010. I'll give the complete code, here. Thanks for answers!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {   
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\lumi\\Desktop\\Test_DataB.accdb");
 OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void indexBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.indexBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.test_DataBDataSet);

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'test_DataBDataSet.Index' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.indexTableAdapter.Fill(this.test_DataBDataSet.Index);

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
               try
    {       con.Open();               
            ad.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("Insert @Birth_month, @Firstname, @Surname, @ID", con);
            ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Birth_month", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Firstname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text.ToString();
            ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Surname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox3.Text.ToString();
            ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
            ad.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
    }


               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
               }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What..? Your OleDbCommand looks not a valid sql statement. o.O

Comment: I translated it, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for an INSERT command is

```
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES(list of comma separated values or parameters)
```

So you query lacks of something very important, the table name where the insert should occur.
I am a bit perplexed that you don't get any error message from that.

```
ad.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand(@"Insert INTO table 
                                      VALUES (@Birth_month, @Firstname, @Surname, @ID)", con);
```

And for the purpose of this query you could leave the OleDbDataAdapter out. It is not needed

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(.....);
....
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Keep in mind that this form of INSERT requires that you specify as parameters every value for the fields in the underlying table in the exact order of definition. If you have less parameters than columns then you need to specify a column list before the VALUES

```
INSERT INTO tablename (comma separated list of columns) VALUES (comma separated list of values)
```

By the way, this is the preferred method to follow. In particular this keeps you shielded by schema changes like adding a new nullable column that would break the first statement (the one without the column list)

Answer (score 0):

You can't parameterize your column names. You can parameterize your *values*.

Here the syntax of [`INSERT (Transact-SQL)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx)

```
INSERT 
{
        [ TOP ( expression ) [ PERCENT ] ] 
        [ INTO ] 
        { <object> | rowset_function_limited 
          [ WITH ( <Table_Hint_Limited> [ ...n ] ) ]
        }
    {
        [ ( column_list ) ] 
        [ <OUTPUT Clause> ]
        { VALUES ( { DEFAULT | NULL | expression } [ ,...n ] ) [ ,...n     ] 
        | derived_table 
        | execute_statement
        | <dml_table_source>
        | DEFAULT VALUES 
        }
    }
}
```

For your case;

```
INSERT INTO YourTableName VALUES(@Birth_month, @Firstname, @Surname, @ID)
```

You should add column names if they are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your Insert query seems wrong

```
 ad.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand  Insert into tablename (Birth_month,Firstname,Surname,id) values (@Birth_month, @Firstname, @Surname, @ID)
 ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Birth_month", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
 ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Firstname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text.ToString();
 ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Surname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox3.Text.ToString();
 ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
 ad.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
 con.Close();
```

Make sure your connection string like
  `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;`

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** Your `INSERT INTO` statement is not valid.

Syntax of `INSERT INTO` statement:

`INSERT INTO [TableName]([col1],[col2],[coln]) values(@val1,@val2,@valn);`

**Solution :** assuming your table name is `UserInfo`

```
con.Open();               
ad.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO UserInfo values(@Birth_month, @Firstname, @Surname, @ID", con);   
ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Birth_month", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Firstname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text.ToString();
ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Surname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox3.Text.ToString();
ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
ad.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data.OleDb;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\lumi\\Desktop\\Test_DataB.accdb");
            OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();


            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void indexBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.Validate();
                this.indexBindingSource.EndEdit();
                this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.test_DataBDataSet);

            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'test_DataBDataSet.Index' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
                this.indexTableAdapter.Fill(this.test_DataBDataSet.Index);

            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {

               con.Open();  

                    SqlCeCommand insert_command = new SqlCeCommand("Luna_nasterii,Nume,Prenume,Nr_fisa) " + "VALUES (@Luna_nasterii, @Nume, @Prenume, @Nr_fisa)", con);

                    insert_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Luna_nasterii", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                    insert_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nume",OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text.ToString();
                    insert_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prenume",  OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox3.Text.ToString();
                    insert_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nr_fisa",  OleDbType.Numeric).Value = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);


                    create_adapt.InsertCommand = insert_command;
                    insert_command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.close();
                }


                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Error:  The type or namespace name 'SqlCeCommand' could not be found

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, my first mistake was the syntax of the INSERT statement where I did not pay attention. But even correcting, it did not work. No data was stored in the DB. The problem was that the Access Data Base was not localized in the BIN folder of the project. When I moved it, all worked correctly. Thank you all for help!